# what is similar code for following code?

Tags: java, syntax

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
this.area[y][x + i] = tmp != null ? String.valueOf(tmp.charAt(i)) : " ";
```

Is this similar by following code?

```
if(tmp != null){
   this.area[y][x + i] = String.valueOf(tmp.charAt(i));
} else {
   this.area[y][x + i] = "";
}
```

Comment: despite the missing whitespace in your else clause and in terms of assignemt of the value, yes

Comment: yes this is the same

Comment: The first on is just a syntactic sugar.  Both are same

Comment: You could have ran them both and tried.

Answer (score 5):

Nope they are not same! You having space in [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), but not in `if-else`. Same/similar code would be,

```
if(tmp != null){
this.area[y][x + i] = String.valueOf(tmp.charAt(i));
} else {
this.area[y][x + i] = " "; //observe white-space, maybe important for your case
}
```

Comment: Although the missing space is most likely not intended (and just a mistake), this correctly answers the questions as it is.

Comment: We can't be sure about the space, it might be relevant in some scenarios :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look in ternary operator in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) doc. It's exactly this code:

```
if(tmp != null){
   this.area[y][x + i] = String.valueOf(tmp.charAt(i));
} else {
   this.area[y][x + i] = " ";  // space!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called the Ternary operator. It is just a shorter version of the if-then operator.

```
variable x = (expression) ? value if true : value if false
```

So basically your both pieces of code to the same.

Comment: You could say the output of both code are same but not *basically your both pieces of code to the same.*

Comment: "*This is called the Ternary operator*" to be more precise this *is* ternary operator because it consists of three operands. People tend to name it *ternary* because Java has only one operator with three operands, but it is possible that in future Java will add more ternary operators so it is better to call this operator with its proper name, which is *conditional operator*.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet:

```
this.area[y][x + i] = tmp != null ? String.valueOf(tmp.charAt(i)) : " ";
```

is called the ternary operator. It is a short hand version of an `if-else` statement.
 
**Format**:

```
boolean x = (boolean-expression) ? value-if-true : value-if-false
```